# Site displays diff in IE9 than IE8 today

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems trouble shooting the difference in display between IE8 (works fine) and IE9 for the site:
http://www.exploreolympics.com/

Seems this problem just developed, both browsers had displayed the same two days ago.
In IE9 the right 2/3s (below the header) doesn't seem to fit and is dropped down below the left 1/3 panel.
It seem that there should be sufficient room as I review the CSS... but I must be missing something.
CSS file is here:
http://www.exploreolympics.com/style...in_styles3.css

Best wishes

Answer (score 0):

You have float left on your div with id "l_third" shouldn't this be float:right for this?

I have tried this on ie9 but it doesnt fix the issue. In the situation i would normally have the right content before the left content in your html. Try swapping the div#l_third with div#r_2thirds. Also add float:right to div#r_2thirds.

Ive copied your html to give you an idea of what i mean - http://jsfiddle.net/pjsSn/

This link will be very hard to read. I would suggest using it in notepad++ to see how i have swapped the 2 sections over

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try and answer this... will test your suggestions.